# Integer cannot be null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make my app calculate something when the user has inputted a value. I am using a "onChanged" function within the TextField to set a string to the value inputted. Then I am trying to parse this to an integer, but I am receiving that it can't be null and crashing my app. How can I make my tryParse execute after the onchange, and make it available to the rest of the app? At the moment it only makes it available inside that TextField if I put it there, and if I put it outside my class it crashes the app cause the int is null.

```
import 'package:anestesi_v1/shared/drawer.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

String sth1;
String sth2;
int valueAlder = int.tryParse(sth2);



TextEditingController tec = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController tec2 = new TextEditingController();
class BarneAnestesi extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/BarneAnestesi';

  List<Widget> containers = [
    Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget> [
            new ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.line_weight),
              title: new TextField(
                controller: tec,
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Vekt"),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                onChanged: (newVal){
                  if (newVal.length ==1) {
                    sth1 = newVal;
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            new ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.baby_changing_station),
              title: new TextField(
                controller: tec2,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Alder"),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                onChanged: (newVal2) {
                  if (newVal2.length ==1) {
                    sth2 = newVal2;

                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            new ListTile(

              title: new Text('Tubestørrelse: = ${valueAlder ~/ 2+12}'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        // the barnTab widget needs to be assign inside AppBar bottom parameter
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Ane'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
          centerTitle: false,
          // add here to bottom widget
          bottom: barnTab(),
          actions: <Widget> [
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person, color:Colors.white,),
              label: Text('Logg ut',),
              textColor: Colors.white,


            ),
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color:Colors.white,),
              label: Text("Innstillinger"),
              textColor: Colors.white,

            )
          ],),

        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: containers,

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class barnTab extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.child_care,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.article,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class barnTabView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Test1"),
              Text("Test2"),
            ]));
  }
}
```

Updated code:

```
import 'package:anestesi_v1/shared/drawer.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

TextEditingController tec = new TextEditingController();
TextEditingController tec2 = new TextEditingController();

class BarneAnestesi extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = '/BarneAnestesi';

  @override
  _BarneAnestesiState createState() => _BarneAnestesiState();
}

class _BarneAnestesiState extends State<BarneAnestesi> {
  int valueAlder;
  int valueVekt;
  
  void onChanged(newVal2) {
    setState(() => valueAlder = newVal2);
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    List<Widget> containers = [

      Container(

        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Scaffold(

          body: new Column(
            children: <Widget> [
              new ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.line_weight),
                title: new TextField(
                  controller: tec,
                  autofocus: true,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Vekt"),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onChanged: (newVal) {
                    if (newVal.length ==1) {
                      valueVekt = int.tryParse(newVal);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              new ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.baby_changing_station),
                title: new TextField(
                  controller: tec2,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Alder"),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  onChanged: (newVal2) {
                    if (newVal2.length ==1) {
                      valueAlder = int.tryParse(newVal2);
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              new ListTile(
                title: new Text('Tubestørrelse: ${valueAlder != null ? valueAlder ~/4+4: ''}'),
              ),
              new ListTile(
                  title: new Text('Tubelengde i cm: ${valueAlder != null ? valueAlder ~/ 2+12 : ''}')
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
      )
    ];

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        // the barnTab widget needs to be assign inside AppBar bottom parameter
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Ane'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
          centerTitle: false,
          // add here to bottom widget
          bottom: barnTab(),
          actions: <Widget> [
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person, color:Colors.white,),
              label: Text('Logg ut',),
              textColor: Colors.white,


            ),
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color:Colors.white,),
              label: Text("Innstillinger"),
              textColor: Colors.white,

            )
          ],),

        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        drawer: MyDrawer(),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: containers,

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class barnTab extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.child_care,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.article,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class barnTabView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Test1"),
              Text("Test2"),
            ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue stems from the `int` parsing only being done once as you are oddly using global variables and only doing the parsing in the `int` variable initialization.

Since you are not using the `String` global variables anywhere, they should be removed and the `int` variable should be moved into the class. Move the `tryParse` to within each `onChanged` and do a check for if the `int` is `null` before displaying the `int` in the `Text` widget or initialize it to some value beforehand.

There's the additional problem of this being a stateless widget, so you will not be able to see updates to the number without using `setState` in a `StatefulWidget`.

onChanged changes:

```dart
onChanged: (newVal2) {
  if (newVal2.length ==1) {
    valueAlder = int.tryParse(newVal2);
  }
},
```

Text widget changes:

```dart
Text('Tubestørrelse: = ${valueAlder != null ? valueAlder ~/ 2+12 : 'null'}')
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my thread thoroughly. I am new to Flutter and Dart (been learning in my spare time for about 2 weeks), so things might be weirdly coded.

I have updated my code in the main post with your suggestions and help. I am getting an error on the valueAlder when trying to parse it inside the TextField. The error is "The instance member valueAlder can't be accessed in an initializer'. I've brought the ints inside the class, mind helping me understand this?

Comment: @Veritaas Do not edit out your original question. Rollback your edit to your original code and *add* your modified code. Additionally, specify *where* this error is.

Comment: I managed to fix the instance member error. It was because the int's weren't inside the builder. Also I've rolled back the changes. The only issue remaining is that the textfields aren't updating when the user inputs numbers into the textfields. I thought the "onChanged" would update the fields, but alas I was wrong. Been trying to google a solution but I can't seem to comprehend how this works.

Comment: @Veritaas You did not use `setState` like I said.

Comment: My apologies, I have now included the setState like you said, but it seems like I don't understand how to use the setState correctly, as this does not update the app based on my input. I've updated the code again in the main post.

Comment: @Veritaas Wrap `valueAlder = int.tryParse(newVal2);` and the other one in `setState`. What you did does nothing as that function is never called.

Comment: After tinkering and trying I figured it out on my own, but I did what you said. "onChanged: (newVal2) {
                    setState(() {   if (newVal2.length ==1) {
                      valueAlder = int.tryParse(newVal2);
                    }
                  },);},"

Thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

The `sth1` and `sth2` should have default values, for example:

```
String sth1='0';
String sth2='0';
```

Comment: How do I make the TextField with the calculation update to the inputted int? At the moment it autocalculates with the ints default value and doesn't change.

Comment: @Veritaas you should use stateful widget. i think thats also a part of the problem

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am trying to implement it into a stateful widget now!